# "mySql" store the output of SQL command into file with beautiful format

Tags: mysql

I want to store output of select command into a file.
I find this command "select * from logInfo into outfile 'tmp.txt'".

when I type "select * from logInfo". the output has good format.
for example:

```
+-----------------------------+-----------------+----------------------------+
| avg(TimeInWaitingScanQueue) | avg(TimeofScan) | avg(TimeInSendResultQueue) |
+-----------------------------+-----------------+----------------------------+
|                     47.3542 |        132.0568 |                     1.4032 |
+-----------------------------+-----------------+----------------------------+
```

but the content in the output file is like this:

```
47.3542 132.0568        1.4032
```

Is there any method which make the content in output file also has the beautiful format?

Comment: What is "the beautiful" format? You mean - you want to keep delimiters & formatters like in mysql CLI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the following with MySQL command line client:

```
PAGER cat > /tmp/mysql-output.txt
SELECT * FROM logInfo;
```

Downside is that this doesn't work if executed through PHP, ODBC or any other means.

Comment: Tnx very much. It works. but unfortunately, I am trying to access the DB through Python, not should if this method can work. I will try it.